# If it has children remove href from parent, else

Tags: jquery, navigation, html-lists

I have a list of menu items with sub uls and sub-sub uls. for the sub-sub uls I'd like to remove the href from the parent only if the parent has children.

This is what i have so far, not really sure how to transform it to an if -> else statements.

```
$('#menu-sidebar-menu > li > ul:has(li) > a').children(['li']).find('a:first').removeAttr('href');

<li class="cat-item cat-item-89"><a href="#" title="Detailed posts for products.">Products</a>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-100"><a href="#" title="Detailed posts for products.">ALL</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-94"><a href="#" title="Post about products for Ducati sportbikes.">Ducati</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-91"><a href="#" title="Posts about products for Honda sportbikes.">Honda</a>
    <ul class='children'>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-104"><a href="#" title="testing">CBR 1000RR</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-103"><a href="#" title="TESTING">CBR 600RR</a>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-93"><a href="#" title="Post about products for Kawasaki sportbikes.">Kawasaki</a>
```

Thank you so much for any input.

Sergio

Comment: post your **markup** too.

Comment: its from a standard wordpress categories configuration...pretty lengthy - li > ul > il > ul > li

Comment: At least you can add some part of it, without seeing your markup we won't be able to help.

Comment: ok no problem. Just add a particular li > ul > il > ul > li setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$.each($("ul > li"), function (index, obj) {
    if ($(obj).has("ul").length) {
        $(obj).has("ul").find("a:first").removeAttr("href");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-89"><a href="#" title="Detailed posts for products.">Products</a>

        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-100"><a href="#" title="Detailed posts for products.">ALL</a>

            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-94"><a href="#" title="Post about products for Ducati sportbikes.">Ducati</a>

            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-91"><a href="#" title="Posts about products for Honda sportbikes.">Honda</a>

                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-104"><a href="#" title="testing">CBR 1000RR</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-103"><a href="#" title="TESTING">CBR 600RR</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-93"><a href="#" title="Post about products for Kawasaki sportbikes.">Kawasaki</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: @Sergio sorry for the late reply and yeah have slightly modified your markup.

Comment: Hi Moksh, my apologies for not cleaning up the markup...it was like 2 in the morning here and I was ready to pass out :-) It worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much for your help.